# Difference between sqrt and sqrtf

Tags: c++, floating-point

I want to consider to code. First it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int s = 25;
    cout << sqrt(s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gave me this mistake:

```
>c:\users\datuashvili\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\training\training\training.cpp(9): error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(589): could be 'long double sqrt(long double)'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(541): or       'float sqrt(float)'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(127): or       'double sqrt(double)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I add type float in brackets in front of s, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int s = 25;
    cout << sqrt((float)s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got as I would guess, `5`. And another variant is that instead of `sqrt`, if I write `sqrtf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int s=25;
    cout << sqrtf((float)s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also got `5`.

What is the difference between them? Does it means that sqrtf is same as sqrt for the float type?

Comment: But you won't get an error you compile it in g++ (GNU compiler)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's [a page on MSDN documentation for `sqrt()` and `sqrtf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1xa99e6.aspx), that explains the difference:

> **sqrt, sqrtf**
>
> Calculates the square root.
>
> ```
>     double sqrt(
>        double x 
>     );
>     float sqrt(
>        float x 
>     );  // C++ only
>     long double sqrt(
>        long double x
>     );  // C++ only
>     float sqrtf(
>        float x 
>     );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *x*: Nonnegative floating-point value
>
> **Remarks**
>
> C++ allows overloading, so users can call overloads of
>   **sqrt** that take float or long double types. In a C program, **sqrt** always
>   takes and returns double.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The **sqrt** function returns the square-root of x. If x
>   is negative, **sqrt** returns an indefinite, by default.

So the difference in C++ is that `sqrt()` accepts either a `double`, a `float` or a `long double` while `sqrtf()` accepts only a `float`.

As the documentation says, the only reason why there's two different versions is because C did not support overloading, so there had to be two functions. C++ allows overloading, so there are actually three different versions of `sqrt()` taking floating point arguments of various sizes.

So in C++, both your code snippets do essentially the same thing. On C, however, there would've been a conversion from `float` to `double` in the `sqrt()` call.

Comment: one question if sqrt   accepts a double then why it does works if add float type in front of integer?should not it be double?

Comment: "So the difference is that sqrt() accepts a double" - only in C, in C++ it's overloaded to accept any FP type.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Oops. Removed comment.

Comment: @In silico: fine, I'll remove mine. :)

Comment: In C, if `<tgmath.h>` is included then `sqrt((float)x)` actually calls `sqrtf`

Answer (score 4):

C did not support function overloading. That means that there had to be one different function for each type. Hence a `sqrt` for `double` and `sqrtf` for `float`. Since `double` was the "preferred" type for floating point numbers in C, then the "default" version was the one for `double`. Both are part of the C standard library, in `math.h`.

In C++, the overloaded `sqrt` (defined in `cmath`, in namespace `std`) should be used.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the `sqrt` function is overloaded to take either a `double`, a
`float` or a `long double` as argument.  When you pass an `int`, all
three can be called, and there's no way for the compiler to choose one
over the others, so the call is ambiguous.  If you explicitly convert
the `int` to `float`, of course, one of the three is an exact match,
whcih makes it better than the other two, so it gets called.

The function `sqrtf` is from C; in C, there is no overloading; `sqrt` is
always `sqrt(double)`, and `sqrtf` takes a `float`.  Since this function
isn't overloaded, calling it can't result in an ambiguity.

Comment: which means if I have a C++ code, I don't need to have sqrtf, right?

Comment: Note: The behaviour described in the first paragraph was true in C++03; however C++11 changed it so that `int` argument invokes the `double` overload (see C++11 [c.math]/11 or C++17 [cmath.syn]/2)

Answer (score 2):

`sqrtf` is a heritage of C.

In C++ we have overloading, and the `sqrt` function has different overloads for the three floating-point types. In C, instead, there's no overloading, thus the various versions of the square root function must be distinguished with the name of the function; hence we have `sqrt` (that in C works only on `double`s) and `sqrtf` for `float`s.

Comment: I never knew this was different in Canada !

Comment: @Paul: that's what happens when you write from a phone with an overzealous autocorrect. :)

Comment: @PaulR [Your typo is famous.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22I+never+knew+this+was+different+in+Canada!%22&ia=qa)

Answer (score 0):

## `sqrtf()` is faster than `sqrt()`

...but you pay a price in precision.

```
C:\Users\ceilingcat> type f.cc
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
int main(){
  double f=0;
  int i=0;
  for( ; i <= 2000000000; f+=sqrt(i++) );
  std::cout.precision( 20 );
  std::cout<<f<<'\n';
}
C:\Users\ceilingcat> cl f.cc /Ox /arch:AVX2 /fp:fast /Qfast_transcendentals
C:\Users\ceilingcat> time ./f.exe
59628479422355.53125

real    0m3.846s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s

C:\Users\ceilingcat> type g.cc
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
int main(){
  double f=0;
  int i=0;
  for( ; i <= 2000000000; f+=sqrtf(i++) );
  std::cout.precision( 20 );
  std::cout<<f<<'\n';
}
C:\Users\ceilingcat> cl g.cc /Ox /arch:AVX2 /fp:fast /Qfast_transcendentals
C:\Users\ceilingcat> time ./g.exe
59628479422157.773438

real    0m2.104s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

N.B. I used some crazy compiler flags to highlight the difference on my hardware. Unless you really know what you're doing, you should probably use more conservative flags.

Comment: That's not what this question is about ... change your first code to `sqrt((float)i++)`.  You are really (purporting to) demonstrate performance difference between `sqrt<float>` and `sqrt<double>`

Comment: The actual benchmark is not very good either as you have got three operations in each iteration  (integer to floating conversion, square root, and floating addition). All three of those might have different performance characteristics for `float` vs. `double`