# c++ DLL: Include classes from project

Tags: c++, dll, include

Case: I'm making an application that should be able to get all DLLs that are in a certain folder and load those. These DLLs act as modules and should be able to perform certain tasks that may or may not take place in the main application.

To allow access from my DLL to the main application I've added the main application's folder to the DLL's Additional Include Directories. This works up to the point where I can call `#include` on my main application's header files and use it's classes and functions.

The problem: Includes that are in the main application's header files seem to cause problems in the DLL trying to access functions from these Includes. For example: I've got a class 'Target' in my main application. This class has 1 include:

```
#ifndef D3DX9_INCLUDED
#define D3DX9_INCLUDED
#include <d3dx9.h> // Direct3D 9
#endif
```

If I include Target.h in my DLL, I'm getting 4 identical errors:

```
Error   2   error C3861: 'sqrtf': identifier not found  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx9math.inl  1585    1   WW
Error   3   error C3861: 'sqrtf': identifier not found  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx9math.inl  1717    1   WW
Error   4   error C3861: 'sqrtf': identifier not found  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx9math.inl  1862    1   WW
Error   5   error C3861: 'sqrtf': identifier not found  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx9math.inl  2032    1   WW
```

If I remove the original include from the Target class, there's no errors anymore. <strike>I can include d3dx9 in my DLL without problems, but only when it's not included in the Target class.</strike> Including d3dx9.h directly into my DLL gives the exact same errors as above. Obviously this doesn't help since I need that include for certain classes and functions in the Target class as well as in the DLL.

Am I looking for a different type of file instead of DLLs for modules? Is there anything I should keep in mind regarding to includes when working with DLLs?

If I forgot to add any info, please let me know and I will do what I can.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Stripped down the DLL to the bare minimum with just the math.h and d3dx9.h includes still give me the same errors.

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <d3dx9.h> // Direct3D 9


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: There are some interesting complications with trying to call functions in the EXE from a DLL it loads, but your problem is much simpler.  Have you tried `#include <math.h>` ahead of including this other header?

Comment: Yeah I was afraid there would be complications with this. Tried looking around for quite a bit but most people are doing the exact opposite, which makes more sense hehe. I tried including math.h but no luck unfortunately. It keeps giving the same errors.

Comment: I also found out that for some reason directly including d3dx9.h into the DLL gives the exact same errors. I guess this didn't happen before because of incorrect building of the project and dll. I've added this info to the main post.

Comment: Have you included windows.h before any of the directx stuff?

Comment: Will try as soon as I can. What I'm wondering: Includes have to happen for the DLL seperately even when the application has a certain include? and how could loading the DLL trigger errors on the includes in the main application rather than on the DLL? I'll try the windows.h include in the DLL and let you know when I can!

Comment: Every single .cpp gets compiled completely separately.  If a .cpp file includes a header, it needs to include everything that header needs.  It's not sufficient for some other .cpp file to include the stuff the header depends on.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Unfortunately adding the Windows.h header file before including d3dx9.h does not change the situation. I have the math.h included inbetween. After looking at the errors a bit more I found something interesting: Even though i get the "'sqrtf': identifier not found" errors, when I look at these 'sqrtf' calls in the d3dx9math.inl file and they're not showing any errors. Going to the definition of the calls pops up the math.h file like it should, even though the errors are still listed when building the DLL.

Comment: After doing some more research I've found that there are more situations where sqrtf is undefined. Apparently sqrtf is the float version used in C since C did not support overloading. C++ should be used according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7431081/2976851. I think there is something wrong with my std includes since when trying to include math.h I get even more errors similar to the sqrtf ones. Is it possible that a base include related to std has to be included differently in a DLL than in a Win32 project? Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're using a C-compatible header, so it doesn't matter what good C++ style is, you need to `#include <math.h>` because that is what this header expects.  `<math.h>`, not `<cmath>`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I stripped down my DLL to the bare minimum, just including math.h and d3dx9.h: (I'll place the code in the main post, kitten formatting in comments)

Comment: Get rid of `stdafx.h` (you may have to get rid of the `/Yu` compiler options also) and add `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: Okay so after trying that and finding out it didn't work I thought it might have something to do with me including the main application directory into my DLL which I needed to do for my DLL to be able to access my application. I removed that include from my DLL's properties and BOOM errors gone. Apparently it doesn't like me including the application to the DLL. It doesn't make any sense to remove stdafx.h from my application so would you perhaps have any clue on the approach here and if it's even possible to access the application from a DLL that is being loaded using LoadLibrary?

Comment: Ahh, now we're getting into the complexity I originally mentioned.  You have a couple options: 1. Put just about the entire application into a DLL, and the main EXE just loads and calls this app-logic DLL.  Then the plugin DLLs can use the app-logic DLL also.  2. Export functions from the main application and create an export library for the EXE.  3. Don't let the plugin DLL make calls directly to the main application, instead when the application loads a plugin, it passes a context object to the plugin init function.  That context contains pointers to functions the plugin might need.

Comment: Aha! The third option seems the easiest to implement, but does it also work with passing a reference to a function/class in the main application? What I'm trying to do is access a class's functions and properties.

Comment: Use the usual COM-like decoupling technique -- a base class with only pure virtual functions and no data.  The application can use the implementation classes throughout, but the plugins will only access the interface and make virtual calls.  That way the plugins don't have to know about the main app allocator or class layout; as long as the virtual functions are listed in the right order, everything can be found.

Comment: I'm going to try this, I'm sure this or one of the other options will work. Thank you so much for all your time and help! If you'd like to you can post the options you gave me as an answer and I will accept it for other people facing this problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to the reason you're having misbehaving header files, although starting from a minimal example with NO precompiled header and only including `<windows.h>`, `<math.h>`, and `<d3dx9.h>` should get you on your way to solving those.

For the larger problem of how to allow plugin DLLs to reuse functionality from the main application, there are basically three approaches, which differ in complexity and coupling.  You probably don't want to require all future plugins to be built with the exact same compiler, do you (or be unable to move the main application to a new compiler until all plugins are also ready to move simultaneously).

1. Put just about the entire application into a DLL, and the main EXE just loads and calls this app-logic DLL. Then the plugin DLLs can use the app-logic DLL also.
2. Export functions from the main application and create an import library for the EXE.  `__declspec(dllexport)` works inside EXEs too.  Some tweaking of build options needed to tell the linker to create an import library.
3. Don't let the plugin DLL make calls directly to the main application, instead when the application loads a plugin, it passes a context object pointer to the plugin init function. That context contains pointers to functions the plugin might need.  The context can also be supplied later, when plugin functions are used, instead of during loading/init.

All of these cases benefit from decoupling techniques which COM programmers are familiar with.  Basically the API should consist of only three kinds of types:

1. Primitives
2. Plain old data structures.  All data members are non-static and public, no non-trivial special member functions.
3. Pointers to interfaces.  Interfaces are base classes with only pure virtual functions and no data.

The key thing about these is that they have a consistent memory layout across different compiler versions, different vendors, and even different languages.  Sometimes you need `#pragma pack` to get the ultimate level of layout control.

Another thing we learn from COM is to have factories and let objects free their own memory with a `Release()` virtual member function.  To support shared_ptr-like reference counting, COM uses `AddRef()` and `Release()` pairs.  The important thing here is that when the code to destroy the object is part of the object, it automatically uses the memory allocator in the same module as the factory.

One thing that COM does that you don't need to is the factory interface.  Most of the time simple factory functions are more than good enough.